# "Trying to get property of non-object" After "multi_query"

Tags: php, properties

This error only appears when i reload page with form where im using

```
> multi_query
```

In this line

```
if($rezultat->num_rows > 0) {
```

Before that i have

```
$rezultat = $polaczenie->query("SELECT * FROM `produkty` ORDER BY `id_produktu`");
```

If i will not use my form with multi_query this error doesn't appear

Comment: what database adapter are you using anyway?

Comment: How can i know that? Im using xampp 3.2.2

Comment: Mixing `query()` and `multi_query()` in the same script can cause issues. Try putting this line somewhere between the 2 queries: `while ($polaczenie->next_result()) {;}`